# get result filtered by count grouped by date in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I am working on CakePHP 3.4

I am building some application which uses API key. One key is limited to 100 calls per day, so I'm using multiple keys and want to loop through it.

In my controller, I'm calling a model's function to get API

```
$api_key = $this->CustomApi->getKey();
if (!$api_key) {
    $this->Flash->error(__('API key not found'));
} else {
    ...
}
```

In model `CustomApi` I want to write `getKey()` function which will find Api key whose call count of the day is less than 100.

Columns of `custom_api` table are `id`, `api_key` and calls are recorded in `api_calls` table whose columns are `id`, `user_id`, `custom_api_id`, `created`

Everytime user access function which requires API, a record is created in `api_calls` table with the time call has been made and primary key of the custom_api.

**My question is, How to get Api key from `CustomApi` model whose call counts are less than 100 for that day (ie., today)**

> Edit 2 : My Try

```
$key = $this
    ->find()
    ->select(['CustomApi.id', 'CustomApi.api_key'])
    ->where(['CustomApi' => /* count is less than 100 */])
    ->leftJoinWith('ApiCalls', function ($q) {
          return $q->where(['ApiCalls.created' => date('Y-m-d')]);
    })
    ->group('CustomApi.id');
```

**How to make a count in `where`?**

Comment: Left join with `ApiCalls` where `created` is in the bounds of today, group `CustomApi` by its primary key, and select only those `CustomApi`s having a count of `ApiCalls`s less than 100.

Comment: ok, trying what you said

Comment: Hello ndm, please check `edit 2`. Is it correct against what you said? How to make a count in `where`. I tried googling but nothing found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there, you need to use a `HAVING` clause, `WHERE` won't work here, as it works on single results, rather than on aggregated ones, which is what you need here.

SQL functions can be built using the function builder, and in order to create a comparison with a function expression, you'll have to leavarege the expression builder, using for example the `lt()` (less than) method.

```
$this
    ->find()
    ->select(['CustomApi.id', 'CustomApi.api_key'])
    ->leftJoinWith('ApiCalls', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['ApiCalls.created' => date('Y-m-d')]);
    })
    ->group('CustomApi.id')
    ->having(function ($exp, $q) {
        return $exp->lt(
            $q->func()->count('ApiCalls.id'),
            100
        );
    });
```

And in case `ApiCalls.created` isn't a date only column, you'd use a `BETWEEN` clause, or manually clamp the value using `>=` and `<=` comparisons against the beginning and the end of the day.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\FunctionsBuilder](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.FunctionsBuilder.html)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Expression.QueryExpression.html)**